# Pass Event from Main Page to element in User Control

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls

I have MainPage in WPF Project. This page contains sidebar, which I want to move in UserControl. But this sidebar also has some elements such as `Button` that has `click` events. In codebehind this event is related to viemModel that are binded to MainPage. So I don't want to bind this viewModel to `UserControl`. 
What I want to do - pass this event to user control on MainPage and then this event bind to `Button` in `UserControl`.

Is it possible to do or it is bad idea? Thanks

---

For example :

SideBar has button :

```
<Button Grid.Column="1" Width="44" Height="44" Style="{StaticResource SearchBtn}" Click="Search_TextChanged" >
    <Button.Content>
            <Image Height="15" Width="15" Source="/Assets/icon-search.png"/>
    </Button.Content>
</Button>
```

Click event is related to `ViewModel`

```
private void Search_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _resultViewModel.Search_TextChanged(tbSearch.Text);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it is better not to use the code behind especially not the click events. I would suggest to use MVVM pattern inside you application This way you can use commands for the click events this can also bubble up on the stack.

And you can also share the ViewModel over the mainpage and maybe your usercontrol

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Jordy, you should implement a MVVM pattern inside your application.  You could look at MVVM Light https://mvvmlight.codeplex.com/ or get from the nuget package manager.  With MVVM Light you will be able to handle button click events using Relay Commands and able to communicate between user controls with their built in Messenger.